# MySQL error 1054 en PhpMyAdmin Localhost

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla propietario con datos del cliente y otra abonoanticipado que es una tabla que almacena informacion sobre los pagos del mismo. A la hora de hacer una consulta para obtener y mostrar (si la suma de todos los pagos del mes supera los 200$) me ocurre dicho error. Quien sera tan amable de orientarme, no con la resolución como tal, sino mas bien para que pueda entender el concepto de las funciones y reconocer la forma de pensarlo correctamente. Gracias.

```
SELECT nombre, apellido, fecha, SUM(montocobrado) AS TOTAL

FROM estacionamiento.propietario

INNER JOIN estacionamiento.abonoanticipado ON propietario.idPropietario=abonoanticipado.idPropietario

AND TOTAL>=200

GROUP BY propietario.DNI
```

> *La columna "TOTAL" en Where Clause es desconocida.*

Comment: Para poder ayudarte necesitaríamos ver la estructura de las tablas; los campos que incluye y el tipo de datos que acepta

Comment: Me temo que no puedes usar un valor de alias en un where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para filtrar por un valor calculado debes usar **HAVING** de esta manera:

```
SELECT nombre, apellido, fecha, SUM(montocobrado) AS TOTAL
  FROM estacionamiento.propietario
 INNER JOIN estacionamiento.abonoanticipado ON propietario.idPropietario=abonoanticipado.idPropietario
 GROUP BY propietario.DNI
HAVING TOTAL>=200
```

Tienes toda la información en la documentación oficial (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html).

Lo que hace el `HAVING` es hacer una comparación (tal como se haría en el `WHERE`) pero después de filtrar los datos, es decir, no se usa en vez del `WHERE` sino junto a el (concretamente después del `WHERE`),  para eliminar resultados que no validan la condición/es establecida.